# Other than conditionals, what function/method to use to return an object that meets certain criteria in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

#COMPLETE BEGINNER
I'm trying to create a custom function in a class that offers a choice from a list based on 2 criteria. Due to my very limited knowledge, I can't think of anything other than conditionals.
I want the function to return `obj2` from `objcollection` in this case (criteria: c= "m" and d= "n")

```
class Blah:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
    
obj1 = Blah("x", "t", "z", "f")
obj2 = Blah("g", "w", "m", "n")
objcollection = [obj1, obj2]
```

Comment: So use conditionals. You have conditions that need to be met, and conditional statements will check to see if they are.

Comment: `return [o for o in objectcollection if o.c == "m" and o.d == "n"]`

Comment: Do you want the function to always apply the same criteria, or do you want to pass it the criteria as an argument?  If so, how?  You might find it easier if the values in `Blah` are a dictionary, rather than individual attributes, since then you can use the keys of the dictionary as identifiers when specifying your filter criteria.

Comment: That's how user-defined classes print.  It's totally normal.  If you want it to print in a prettier format, make a `__str__` method on the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to return an object based on a *condition*, using a conditional (e.g. an `if`) is definitely the right thing.

```
def select_cm_dn(objs):
    return next(o for o in objs if o.c == "m" and o.d == "n")

assert select_cm_dn(objcollection) == obj2
```